# dovecot Mail delivery System returns "unknown user" and client authentication fails

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have dovecot installed on Ubuntu 12.04. I am using Ispconfig3 to manage the virtual users. I have been through the http://wiki2.dovecot.org/TestInstallation process and everything (except the ssl) works:
I can log in using telnet. 
I can open the inbox.

However when I try to send an email to one of the accounts from gmail, the email gets returned from "Mail Delivery System" saying "unknown user: 'test'".
Trying to receive mail using a client gives an authentication error.

There don't seem to be any relevant errors in /var/log/ mail.err or mail.log.

One thing I am suspicious of is that I have not used a sub domain for my mail server and I am not sure if this causes problems. (Now or in the future).

What should I do to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: the error log is CB7D01242D5: to=<test@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.49, delays=0.01/0.38/0/0.1, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "test")

Comment: dovecot.conf: http://pastie.org/6113418 master.cf: http://pastie.org/6113424 main.cf: http://pastie.org/6113428

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Comment: ?!? Sometimes I wonder about why here closed topics are ... For me dovecot and postfix are part of server and network infrastructure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was answered here: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?p=291837

Remove my domain from the mydestination = line in /etc/postfix/main.cf and restart postfix.